# Change the ISO or shutter speed

Tags: iphone, performance, camera

I am tring to control the ISO and the shutter speed for the iphone, but it has no API in AVFoundation. It can only change the exposure, wb for iphone.

How can i control the ISO or shutter speed?

Comment: I don't think you have any more control than that offered by AVCaptureDevice http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/isAdjustingFocus

Comment: camera+ can do this, how can I did it. The lower level API?

Comment: You can do this with private APIs in iOS 6, at least. Hopefully they'll be made public in the next release. Check out my detailed answer here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/12939981/83853

Comment: Feel free to mark this question as a dupe-- I'm not sure how to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing iOS 6 new APIs for camera exposure and shutter speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You unfortunately have very little control over the iPhone camera. You can only lock or unlock the exposure, white balance, and focus modes.

Camera+ actually does not have control over anything you described. It used to be able to as it hacked the hardware, which is naturally a great way to get your app rejected by the reviewers.

I hope that iOS6 will give developers greater control as it is a PITA.

Answer (score 6):

Now after iOS 8 I guess, Now you can change the shutter speed and ISO too.

By using this function

```
- (void)setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:(CMTime)duration ISO:(float)ISO completionHandler:(void (^)(CMTime syncTime))handler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

of AVCapturedevice class you can set shutter speed and ISO value both
for more help you can see the class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/adjustingExposure).

[discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624646-setexposuremodecustom)

refer this app for implementation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014578)

Comment: What about aperture?

Comment: @NikhilManapure aperture - a space through which light passes in an optical or photographic instrument, especially the variable opening by which light enters a camera. In iOS you can not control the aperture of camera of device before iPhone 7. In latest device I am not sure.