# Is it Possible to increase the shutter speed of Camera in iphone programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera

Increase Shutter Speed programmatically using Obj-C ? Is there any API for that?

Comment: Refer to this question.Hope this might help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed/12939981#12939981

Comment: You can achieve this in iOS 6+ 
check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635446/accessing-ios-6-new-apis-for-camera-exposure-and-shutter-speed/12939981#12939981

Comment: check Below link your question is related to this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347515/change-the-iso-or-shutter-speed

Comment: Why do you want to do that? By pressing and holding the camera button you can take rapid pictures as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) .But those answers only says about changing the Exposure rather than the Shutter Speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution...but couldn't implement it till now.

The Founder of Snappy Labs who released an App named Snappy Cam told
"First we studied the fast discrete cosine transform (DCT) algorithms...We then extended some of that research to create a new algorithm that's a good fit for the ARM NEON SIMD co-processor instruction set architecture. The final implementation comprises nearly 10,000 lines of hand-tuned assembly code, and over 20,000 lines of low-level C code. (In comparison, the SnappyCam app comprises almost 50,000 lines of Objective C code.)

JPEG compression comprises two parts: the DCT (above), and a lossless Huffman compression stage that forms a compact JPEG file. Having developed a blazing fast DCT implementation, Huffman then became a bottleneck. We innovated on that portion with tight hand-tuned assembly code that leverages special features of the ARM processor instruction set to make it as fast as possible".

by implementing those algorithm we can increase the shutter speed which has been done in SnappyCam App.

Comment: Snappy cam is no longer in the App Store. Apparently Apple bought it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't change the shutter speed of the camera. All apps that claim to do this do so using post processing - you can however set the shutter speed for video recording on the iPhone 5S.

Comment: The class docs for AVCaptureDevice don't seem to show anything for changing the shutter speed for video recording. How do you do it?